# What is the different between var myFunc = new Object(function myFunc () {}) and function myFunc () {}?

Tags: javascript, object, new-operator

I didn't know you could create a function using new Object:

```
var myFunc = new Object(function myFunc () {})
```

Looking at the console, it seems identical to:

```
function myFunc () {}
```

Is there a reason to use new Object to create a function?

Comment: You saw the first code somewhere or you yourself created it?

Comment: I created it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Object(...)` [documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

> The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value. If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty object, otherwise, it will return an object of a Type that corresponds to the given value. **If the value is an object already, it will return the value.**

Functions are objects, therefore it will just return the function. The `new Object(...)` part is a no-op. So the code is basically just:

```
  var myFunc = function myFunc() { }
```

and that is [barely equal to a function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Thank you. I created that code from reading that documentation. Can't believe I missed that line. It is pretty late. 

To rephrase my other question, other than how they are defined, are functions created via function expressions identical to those created via function declarations? That's what I meant.

Comment: I did see the link. I already know the difference in how they are defined as the code runs. I know about hoisting. Other than that, is everything else identical?